# How can I make rigged eyes stay on top of another rigged object?

Tags: rigging, constraints, parent

I have recently created two rigged objects, one is representing a rigged letter and the other is rigged eyes. I have managed to make the letter to deform as I wish using the rig and the same goes for the eyes. Now I want to combine the two (note I have used two different armatures for each object). I basically want the eyes to follow the deformation of the letter. Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Does anyone know a quick way to fix this issue? I have tried adding empty axes so that the eyes are clamped to the axes and the axes are clamped to the lattice but this didnt solve my issue. I have also tried parenting which actually does solve the problem but creates an additional eye in between which bothers me and I can't figure out how to remove it.

[image]

Note I am new to blender so there might be some key things I am missing. Thanks.